# iPhone to PHP to iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, authentication

I am trying to create a login system on an iPhone app but am coming across a bit of a problem. I believe that the code I have is sending the the NSString to the php but it is not echoing back the string like I want it to. What am I doing wrong?

I know the php code isn't doing much right now I just want to see that it is storing the values that I send it.

Thanks!

XCode:

```
    NSString *content = @"myusername=a&mypassword=s";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.php"]];
    urlRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];


    // generates an autoreleased NSURLConnection
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(returnString);

}
```

PHP:

```
echo "first ". $_POST['myusename']." return";  
echo "second ". $_POST['mypassword']." return";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate 2 `NSMutableURLRequest` objects.
I'll try to correct your mistake:

```
NSString *content = @"myusername=a&mypassword=s";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];
...
```

Furthermore the string encodings do not match, that could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

you might need to set the content type of the urlrequest to application/x-www-url-formencoded using the setHttpHeader method on the request